# PHP find JSON node value in irregular json file

Tags: php, json, loops

I have a irregular json file with sub nodes and sub sub nodes and sub sub sub nodes and I currently writing a foreach loop like

```
foreach ($jsondata[locations][0][data_types][0][match_data] as $data) {
        echo $data."<br/>";
}
```

And, it will bring up values that are in parent node but when child nodes are in irregular location I couldn't find a right way to write the logic. I tried something like this.

```
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
              for ($j=0; $j<30; $j++) {
                for($k=0; $k<30; $k++) {
                    foreach ($jsondata[locations][$i][data_types][$j][match_data] as $data) {
                      echo $data."<br/>";
                    }
                    foreach ($jsondata[locations][$i][sublocations][$j][data_types][3][match_data] as $data2) {
                      echo $data2."<br/>";
                    }
                    foreach ($jsondata[locations][$i][sublocations][$j][sublocations][$k][data_types][0][match_data] as $data3) {
                      echo $data3."<br/>";
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
```

That's crawling to most of child nodes but its still not complete. I am still missing few nodes.

Can anyone suggest the best way to perform search for a value for key [matchdata] regardless of the node location.

Comment: what do you mean by `irregular`? it's not valid JSON?

Comment: Its a valid json but the node match_data is sometimes under locations, sometimes under locations->sublocations->data_types and sometimes its hard to find the position. Inside a JSON they are multiple arrays and child arrays, I need to find all the values of match_data in entire JSON file.

Comment: okay, what is `match_data` then? is that a key or is that a value? I suspect that's a key and you wanna get all the values of that key and that key is spread across your json on different levels of nesting? Am I getting it right?

Comment: Also, from your description, I inferred your JSON looks some thing like `{"locations": [ { "data_types": [ { "match_data": "THIS IS THE VALUE YOU WANNA GET" } ] }` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on my assumptions of what you are trying to achieve, what you wanna do is to use recursive function to traverse through all the nesting levels to find your matching key

```
// I expect your json is something like this:
$json = <<<JSON
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "data_types": [
                {
                    "match_data": "THIS IS THE VALUE YOU WANNA GET 1"
                }
            ],
            "sublocations": [
                {
                    "data_types": [
                        {
                            "match_data": "THIS IS THE VALUE YOU WANNA GET 2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "subsublocations": [
                        {
                            "data_types": [
                                {
                                    "match_data": "THIS IS THE VALUE YOU WANNA GET 3"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
JSON;

$jsonAsArray = json_decode($json, true);
$values = allValues($jsonAsArray, 'match_data');
var_export($values);

function allValues($jsondata, $keyname)
{
    $values = [];
    foreach ($jsondata as $key => $value) {
        // if your $value can contain a key we are looking for on it's own
        // the code will be a little different
        // but I'm assuming it's not hard to figure out what the code will be
        if ($key === $keyname) {
            $values[] = $value;
            continue;
        }
        // if key doesnt match and value is nested json object or a list,
        // go one level down and apply same function (recursive call)
        // to find if it has a key that is sought after 
        // if it does, simply merge with what we've found so far
        // in order to add to the results.
        if (is_array($value)) {
            // I could also pass $value instead of $jsondata[$key]
            // as, practically, it is the same thing,
            // but following illustrates the point a little better
            $values = array_merge($values, allValues($jsondata[$key], $keyname));
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want but still I have one issue. To print the response I have to use nested foreach loop as arrays are again nested based on the jSON location.

Comment: @lock you better post that json that you have and desired outcome, cause it's a little bit too abstract for me right now to fully understand what you are trying to achieve.